# JS Worker Performance - Parsing JSON

Tags: javascript, web-worker

I'm experimenting with Workers as my user interface is very slow due to big tasks running in the background.

I'm starting at the simplest tasks such as parsing JSON.  See below for my very simple code to create an async function running on a Worke.

Performance wise there is a big difference between:

```
JSON.parse(jsonStr);
```

and

```
await parseJsonAsync(jsonStr);
```

JSON.parse() takes 1ms whereas parseJsonAsync takes 102ms!

So my question is: are the overheads really that big for running worker threads or am I missing something ?

```
const worker = new Worker(new URL('../workers/parseJson.js', import.meta.url));

export async function parseJsonAsync(jsonStr) {

    return new Promise(
        (resolve, reject) => {

            worker.onmessage = ({
                data: {
                    jsonObject
                }
            }) => {
                resolve(jsonObject);
            };

            worker.postMessage({
                jsonStr: jsonStr,
            });
        }
    );
}
```

**parseJson.js**

```
self.onmessage = ({
    data: {
        jsonStr
    }
}) => {

    let jsonObject = null;

    try {
        jsonObject = JSON.parse(jsonStr);
    } catch (ex) {

    } finally {
        self.postMessage({
            jsonObject: jsonObject
        });
    }
};
```

Comment: How do you measure the time?

Comment: Every time you pass data between both contexts it gets serialized and parsed. But 100ms vs 1 seems excessive. How big is the data? Do you also measure the time to initialize the Worker + fetch its script?

Comment: Time measured using console.time().  Before and after calling the functions.  If the worker init is inside the function it adds another 100ms overhead

Comment: "If the worker init is inside the function it adds another 100ms overhead" does that mean that when it's not "inside the function" you do wait for it to be ready, or do you run your test immediately? I.e do you have a `worker.onmessage = startTest` initial event handler?

Comment: I just tried on my machine, if count the worker init time, I got 40ms~150ms varying overhead. But if I setTimeout to wait for worker init first, then postMessage, I got response in just 1ms.

Comment: Ok thanks for the comments.  I think I'm going to try this library.  Might have been approaching this from the wrong angle.  Need to spend more time on this

https://www.npmjs.com/package/comlink

Comment: @hackape that's interesting.  Not sure why it would behave like that

Comment: Simply because starting a worker thread needs time.

Comment: @ceds I updated the answer with my test results. Quite an interesting topic.

Answer (score -1):

I can now confirm that the overhead of transferring message between threads is pretty big. But the raw performance of worker (at least in executing `JSON.parse`) is close to main thread.

TL;DR: Just compare numbers in 2 tables. Without sending big object via `postMessage`, worker perf is just fine.

---

For test payload `jsonStr`, I create a string of a long list of `[{"foo":"bar"}, ...]` repeat n times. The number of items in `jsonStr` can be tuned by changing `Array.from({ length: number })`.

I then do `postMessage(jsonStr)` to run `JSON.parse` in worker, when done parsing it sends back the parsed `jsonObject`. In main thread just I call `JSON.parse(jsonStr)` directly.

`runTest(delay)` use `setTimeout` to wait until the worker startup to run the actual test. `runTest()` without delay runs immediately so we can measure worker startup time.

Code for the test.

```js
const blobURL = URL.createObjectURL(
  new Blob(
    [
      "(",
      function () {
        self.onmessage = ({ data: jsonStr }) => {
          let jsonObject = null;
          try {
            jsonObject = JSON.parse(jsonStr);
            self.postMessage(["done", jsonObject]);
          } catch (e) {
            self.postMessage(["error", e]);
          }
        };
      }.toString(),
      ")()",
    ],
    { type: "application/javascript" }
  )
);

const worker = new Worker(blobURL);
const jsonStr = "[" + Array.from({ length: 1_000 }, () => `{"foo":"bar"}`).join(",") + "]";

function test(payload) {
  worker.onmessage = ({ data }) => {
    const delta = performance.now() - t0;
    console.log("worker", delta);

    console.log("worker response", data[0]);
  };

  const t0 = performance.now();
  worker.postMessage(payload);

  testParseJsonInMain(payload);
}

function testParseJsonInMain(payload) {
  let obj;
  try {
    const t0 = performance.now();
    obj = JSON.parse(payload);
    const delta = performance.now() - t0;
    console.log("main", delta);
  } catch {}
}

function runTest(delay) {
  if (delay) {
    setTimeout(() => test(jsonStr), delay);
  } else {
    test(jsonStr);
  }
}

runTest(1000);
```

I observe that it takes around 30ms to start the worker on my machine. If test run after worker startup, I got these numbers (unit in milliseconds):

| #items in payload | main | worker |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1,000 | 0.2 | 2.1 |
| 10,000 | 1.3 | 9.8 |
| 100,000 | 15.4 | 73.5 |
| 1,000,000 | 165 | 854 |
| 10,000,000 | 2633 | 15312 |

When payload reaches 10 million items, the worker really struggles (takes 15 seconds). At 10 million items, the `jsonStr` is around 140MB.

But if the worker *does not* send back the parsed `jsonObject`, the numbers are so much better. Just make a little change to above test code:

```js
// worker code changed from:
self.postMessage(["done", jsonObject]);

// to:
self.postMessage(["done", typeof jsonObject]);
```

| #items in payload | main | worker |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1,000 | 0.2 | 1.2 |
| 10,000 | 2.1 | 3.5 |
| 100,000 | 15.7 | 26.2 |
| 1,000,000 | 196 | 232 |
| 10,000,000 | 2249 | 2801 |

---

P.S. I've actually done another test. Instead of `postMessage(jsonStr)`, I used `TextEncoder` to turn the string into ArrayBuffer, then `postMessage(arrayBuffer, arrayBuffer)` which supposedly transfers the underlying memory from main thread directly to worker.

I did not see real difference in terms of time consumed, in fact it gets a little bit slower. Guess sending large string isn't an issue.